# mandar alerta cuando se detecta un url usando javascript con sweet alert2

Tags: javascript, url, sweetalert2

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("jdPYJL") > -1) {
       swal({
  position: 'top-end',
  type: 'success',
  title: 'enviado correctamente',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 1500
})
    }

if(window.location.href.indexOf("falloelenvio") > -1) {
       swal({


  title: 'Solicitud creada pero...',
  text: 'No pudo mandarse el correo, revise su internet',
  showConfirmButton: true,
  imageUrl: 'img/errorinternet.jpg',
  imageWidth: 150,
  imageHeight: 150,
  imageAlt: 'Custom image',
  animation: false

})
    }});
```

lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se ingrese a un link que tenga el nombre = "enviado" salga el mensaje de sweet alert. 
lo intento pero tengo un error que la consola no me quiere mostrar y no entiendo el por que.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El primer error indica que jQuery no está (o todavía no está) cargado.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás teniendo es que estás intentado usar jQuery cuando creo que no está importado. Prueba hacerlo con JS puro:

```
// Sin jQuery (Cuidado, puede no funcionar en antiguos internet explorers)
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    // PON AQUÍ TU CÓDIGO DE SWEETS ALERTS 
}, false);
```